# An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: php, symfony

The following command results in the above error;

```
symfony console doctrine:migrations:execute --up 'DoctrineMigrations\Version20220513151605'
```

Lot's of questions on it but I cant find any that match my scenario (localhost apache vhost, mysql, symfony).

All searches appear to point to a faulty DSN string. What I've tried thus far...

**.env.local**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mi_db?serverVersion=5.7.22-log"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/mi_db?serverVersion=5.7.22-log"
```

with no joy?

help

Answer (score -1):

The "DATABASE_URL" you shown is not a DSN string. That is a connection string from some application. Probably web-based.

To learn the proper way to define DSN you need to read documentation on the MySQL itself.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connectors-apis.html

For cheat sheet you can look here:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

W3Schools have nice tutorial on PHP:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: `DATABASE_URL` is an environment variable to be precise and the web-based application you mention is Symfony which I thought was clear from my description. Ideally Im looking for answers which are based around Symfony without appearing to sound too ungrateful. Thanks